# Install .crt certificate t0 .jks storage

Tags: java, ssl

i got  CA signed certificate with root and intermediate certificates.
I tried to install  certificate in a lot of ways.

But in result after converted storage.jks to txt file.
i saw  that my certificate added as Entry type: trustedCertEntry.

Can i install  CA signed certificate in storage.jks without private key which use for generate csr file ?

Comment: where do you want to install it?

Comment: i want to install in storage.jks then storage connect to tomcat

Comment: `keytool -import -keystore storage.jks -file new.cert`

Comment: this command will only add certificate  in storage.jks but not install

Comment: i really dont understand how  can i install certificate without private key

Comment: What do you believe install means?

Comment: i means after using command  <code>keytool -import -keystore storage.jks -file new.cert</code> i will see a message:  Certificate reply was installed in keystore.

Comment: and in storage.jks it ll be Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry

Comment: http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/1007/

Comment: but provider send me only 3 certificate without any private key. Is it possible to install without key?